# value is not a member of Equals

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add an object to a list (third list), I'm using this code

```
    var okii = result.firstList.find(dimension => firstObj.rank == firstObjRank).map(_.secondList).getOrElse(Seq.empty).find(secondObj => secondObj.rank == secondObjRank).getOrElse(Seq.empty)
    okii.thirdList :+ newObj
```

but I get this error:

value  is not a member of Equals

my structure:

```
"result" : {
    "firstList": [{
        "firstObject": "ObjectFirstList"
    }, {
        "secondList": [{
                "secondObject": "ObjectSecondList"
            },
            "thirdList": [{
                "thirdObject": "ObjectThirdList"
            }]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please show `result`'s full definition.

Comment: Add explicit/expected type to `okii` (+ there is no need for it be `var` instead of `val` as far as I can see)

Comment: please @KevinMeredith check my update

Comment: @cchantep already tried